# Multiplicative characters on quadratic extension of finite fields

Tags: representation-theory

I was reading about representations of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$, where $\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field of characteristic $p\geq 3$ from https://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.4051.pdf. In the proof of Lemma 3.42, the author makes the following claim:

Let $\chi$ and $\psi$ be two characters of $\mathbb F_{q^2}^{*}$, such that their restrictions to $\mathbb{F}_{q}^*$ are equal. Then, the claim is either $\chi = \psi$ or $\chi = \psi \circ F$, where $F$ is the Frobenius automorphism on $\mathbb F_{q^2}^{*}$.

I will greatly appreciate any hint or reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true in general. When $q=p=2$, the group $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is trivial, so all characters of $\mathbb F_{q^2}^\times$ have the same restriction to $\mathbb F_q^\times$. But the trivial character and the non-trivial character are not related via the Frobenius.

---

Counter-example for $q=p=3$: Note that $\mathbb F_9^\times=\mathbb F_3[\sqrt{-1}]^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $8$ with generator $1+\sqrt{-1}$. Now there are characters defined by $1+\sqrt{-1}\to\zeta_8$ and $1+\sqrt{-1}\mapsto\zeta_8^{-1}$, which agree after restricting to $\mathbb F_3^\times=(\mathbb F_9^\times)^4$ but they are not Frobenius conjugate.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $p$ is an odd prime. I have modified the question.

Comment: @MattDamon i edited my answer to include a counter-example for $p=3$. in fact there are counter-examples for every $p$ and $q$!

Comment: In the counter example for p=3, when the first character when restricted to $\mathbb{F_3}^\times$ gives value $\iota$ at $1+\sqrt{-1}$ , while the second character gives the value $-\iota$. Hence, the counter example does not work.

Comment: @MattDamon I don't understand, $1+\sqrt{-1}$ is not an element of $\mathbb F_3$

Comment: I meant $1+\sqrt{-1}$ raised to the power of 4.

Comment: @MattDamon $\zeta_8^4=-1$.